# ScrollView fullScroll cancelled by animation

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm using the following to automatically scroll down to the bottom when a new view is added to follow along the item when the list gets big:

```
mainLayout.addView(newItem);
scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN));
```

But in mainLayout I have following enabled:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

So when the new item is inserted, an animation is displayed and that cancels/messes up the scroll. Is there a way around this?

**EDIT:**

I added a Handler with a runnable as suggested in the comments and the issue is sitll there:

```
Handler newHandler = new Handler();
newHandler.post(() -> scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)));
```

Comment: remove animateLayoutChanges or add scroll in an async thread like Handle().post ..

Comment: @parambirsingh I have added the suggestion you made, but the issue is still there. Look at the OP for the new changes.

Comment: ok did you try postDelayed ? Its not proper way but it can do trick.

Comment: @parambirsingh I tried it and it somewhat works. I'll use it until I find a better solution. Thank you

Comment: cool, please upvote comment if it helped